# Youden index of a meta-analysis of continuous variables

Tags: r, roc

I have done a meta-analysis of continuous variable to identify an outcome, generating a "SMD". Therefore I have "means and SDs" of each group...
How do I calculated the best cut off of this continuous variable to identify the outcome? ROC Youden Index?

I do not have the single values that generated the means and SDs, but only the aggregated means and SDs...

thanks!

I tried searching other solutions that do not entail going back to the raw data but I could not find anything...please help me possibly with "R" code...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Best cutoff" is subject-matter specific. If false positives are just as important as false negatives then the Youden Index is a satisfactory metric.